# Put javascript on page from code behind

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have some other javascript functions that are being set on the onfocus and onblur events of the textbox that I am using. In these functions it calls a generic javascript function that is not related to any controls. I want to know how to just simply spit this function out to the html of the page from the code behind. Something like this...

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "?????", getCounter);
```

EDIT: Here is what I mean

```
public class MVADTextBox : TextBox
        {
 protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
            {
 var getCounter = "<script language=\"javascript\">" +
                                "function GetCounter(input) {" +
                                    //this function gets the number of special characters taht are in a row.
                                    //it is only the grouping of characters that are right after your current position
                                    "var textbox = document.getElementById(input.id);" +
                                    "var mask = textbox.getAttribute('Mask');" +
                                    "var inputCharacters = textbox.getAttribute('InputCharacters');" +
                                    "var tbid = \"#\" + input.id;" +
                                    "var position = $(tbid).caret().start;" +
                                    "var counter = 0;" +
                                    "for (var i = position; i < mask.length; i++) {" +
                                    "     if (mask[i] != '#') {" +
                                    "        counter++;" +
                                    "        if (mask[i + 1] == '#') {" +
                                    "            break;" +
                                    "        }" +
                                    "    }" +
                                    "}" +
                                    "return counter;" +
                               " }" +
                            "</script>";

                            Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "OnFocus", onFocus);
                            Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "GetCounter(input)", getCounter);



var onBlur = "<script language=\"javascript\"> function PopulateField(input) {if (input.value == \"\") {input.value = input.defaultValue; input.className = 'sampleText'; } } </script>";


  Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "OnFocus", onFocus);

  Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "OnBlur", onBlur);
    }
}
```

The on blur method is getting sent to the page.

Comment: Nothing so far is working for me that has been suggested.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Answer:**

I believe that `Page.ClientScript` has been deprecated. You should be using `ClientScriptManager`.

Replace your `"?????"` with the name of the script. Honestly, the name of the script is ***almost*** useless (unless you need to check for its existence later on).

```
ClientScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "myCount", getCounter);
```

**Usage Clarification:**

```
//You must surround your code with script tags when not passing the bool param
ClientScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(),
                   "myCount",
                   "<script>alert('Hey')</script>");

// The last param tells .Net to surround your
// code with script tags (true) or not (false)
ClientScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(),
                   "myCount",
                   "alert('Hey')", true);
```

**Additional Information:**

Signatures from MSDN:

```
public void RegisterStartupScript(
    Type type,
    string key,
    string script
)

public void RegisterStartupScript(
    Type type,
    string key,
    string script,
    bool addScriptTags
)
```

See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.clientscriptmanager.registerstartupscript.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You would put the actual function definition, which you already have in getCounter.  Note that the second parameter which you currently have as `"????"`, as James pointed out, is for the script's *key*, which must be unique from all other scripts registered for this type.  The third parameter is the script itself, and the fourth determines whether script tags are to be added, which needs to be false, since you already added them.

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), 
      "someKeyForThisType", getCounter, false);
```

Comment: This is incorrect. The second parameter is the `key`, not the script.

Comment: @James - thank you, it's fixed.  It's been too long since I used that method, I should have investigated more before answering.

Answer (score 1):

EDITED:

```
 var getCounter = "<script language=\"javascript\">" +
                                        "function GetCounter(input) {" +
            //this function gets the number of special characters taht are in a row.
            //it is only the grouping of characters that are right after your current position
                                            "var textbox = document.getElementById(input.id);" +
                                            "var mask = textbox.getAttribute('Mask');" +
                                            "var inputCharacters = textbox.getAttribute('InputCharacters');" +
                                            "var tbid = \"#\" + input.id;" +
                                            "var position = $(tbid).caret().start;" +
                                            "var counter = 0;" +
                                            "for (var i = position; i < mask.length; i++) {" +
                                            "     if (mask[i] != '#') {" +
                                            "        counter++;" +
                                            "        if (mask[i + 1] == '#') {" +
                                            "            break;" +
                                            "        }" +
                                            "    }" +
                                            "}" +
                                            "return counter;" +
                                       " }" +
                                    "</script>";

        this.TextBox1.Attributes.Add("OnFocus", "GetCounter(this);");
        if (!ClientScript.IsClientScriptBlockRegistered("getCounter")) {
            ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "getCounter", getCounter, false);
        }
```

Comment: by myfuntion do you mean function?

Comment: You have changed your Question. I will Edit accordingly. Could you post the names/IDs of the TextBoxes you want this functions for?

Comment: the "myFunction" in this case is just an alias for this script block, it *almost* doesn't matter what you write there..

Comment: @JonathanO I have modified the answer, please take a look.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to use the ClientScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock method

[Try this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/btf44dc9.aspx)